# ¿Cómo leer un archivo de texto en C# de Internet?

Tags: c#, archivo

Estoy usando esta línea de código que me funciona a la perfección cuando está el archivo en mi ordenador:

`string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"RUTA");`

Pero cuando se trata de una ruta externa, es decir, Google Drive o demás, no consigue leer lo que hay dentro y me da un error.

Estoy tratando de leer lo que pone en un fichero de texto en Unity, he creado un `Script` muy básico con eso pero sin resultados.

Error que me sale:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "C:\Users\Espada\Desktop\Unity Workspace\LearnWash\https:\docs.google.com\document\d\1ErUKOhpmoUFkPPsDkAyvzNLjeB22fTHG0jonEe0XlpE\edit".
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:292)
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>   (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
>   System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs

Answer (score 0):

Si el archivo esta en un hosting o disco en el cloud el primer paso sera descargarlo a una carpeta temporal de la pc, para luego recien poder accederlo

Si es una url comun podrias usar

[WebClient.DownloadFile Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.8)

```
string urlFile = "https:\docs.google.com\document\...";
string fileName = "c:\carpeta\nombrearchivo.txt";

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(urlFile,fileName);
```

despues de descargarlo lo podras leer

Comment: El caso Leandro es que necesito saber qué pone de forma remota sin tener que bajármelo al ordenador. Me refiero, yo tengo que implementar en una App que lea qué pone en un .Txt en drive, es decir, tendrá escrito "1.0" y la App móvil debe leer el 1.0

Comment: lo que planteas no se puede realizar sino accedes al archivo, si es de texto tienes el `WebClient.DownloadString()` quizas si es texto sea mas simple que descargar el archivo. Igual si es un archivo de drive quizas debas evaluar sino hay un cliente .net que debas usar

Comment: Si, pero no me dejaba usar webclient tan facil

Comment: Leandro, pero cuando intento usar webclient falla...

Comment: Me parece que google drive deberias usar la libreria que este servicio tiene https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: Con el servicio puedes leer el archivo, como dice Leandro puedes ir guardando la info al leer el archivo  con una peticion al api drive y tenerlo en memoria del proceso (stream). Lee https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads